# Wrap a C program in Python that reads custom file into a 2d array

Tags: python, c, numpy, swig, cython

I have a stand-alone c program that takes a char* file name, opens the file, reads and decodes it into a 2d array.  We do not know the length of the array until the file is read.  The program mallocs memory.

I would like to have a python extension that returns a 2d numpy integer array, given the file name:

> > > a = readFile("theFileName.dat")

I would like to have python manage the memory once the array is returned.

1. In numpy.i, is there a directive defined I can use with %apply
2. Is cython better suited for this?
3. Other suggestion?

Copying data is OK since the files are not very large.

Comment: not the answer to your question... but why do you need to do it in C if the files arent very large... python is great at parsing files ... and even numpy is great at it... or is this one of those I want to just see if I can type question?

Answer (score 1):

[`SIP`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/SIP) ([here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/sip4/introduction.html) too) can be used to create Python bindings for C libraries.

But that's probably an overkill; it would probably be easier to read/decode your .dat file in Python itself.